# Can I select all react components of a type, without assigning a class to each one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

I have a Playground here: https://codesandbox.io/s/736v9vjzw1

```
const Something = ({ classes, children, variant }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.someThing}>
      <p> I'm some thing </p>

      <SomeOtherThing />

      <SomeOtherThing> I have some children </SomeOtherThing>

      <SomeOtherThing> I have some children </SomeOtherThing>

      <SomeOtherThing> I have some children </SomeOtherThing>
    </div>
  );
};

const styles = {
  someThing: {
    color: "green",
    border: "solid 2px black",
    margin: 30,

    "& $someOtherThing": {
      backgroundColor: "pink" // Doesn't work
    },

    "& p": {
      fontWeight: "bold" //This works but is too broad
    }
  }
};
```

I have a situation here, where I want to style all the `SomeOtherThing`s inside my `SomeThing`.

I can use `& p` selector to select the `p` element - but I don't like this. It would style any random `p`s I have around - and I don't want to have to look inside the component definition to find what it's top level element is.

How can I do this? Something like `& SomeOtherElement`.

The real world application of this, is that in some places I want have `SomeOtherElement` be displayed `block` and other places `inline-block`.

Comment: add a unique class to the parent element of `SomeOtherThing` and use css normally on that class.

Comment: @Chris can you fork the playground and show me?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/53no69o7pk

Comment: Ok, that works - but I'm not sure how. Do you think you can post this as an answer ( you might as well get the points) - the answer would probably be good to point to the jss documentation for that square brackets syntax- coz I've never seen that

Comment: Found similar issue https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss/issues/249, this may help to understand problem

Comment: I'm not sure if you're in the market for another dependency, but `styled-components` solves this really elegantly: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components

Comment: Hello dear @dwjohnston, what's my answer problem? I ask to learn more. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would extend the `SomeOtherThing` component to accept a className and add it to the `div` if present. This will also work on a production setup, where the class names is minified to e.g. `.t-0-root`.

Here is a forked playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/zlzx277zzm which shows how to use it.

```
const SomeOtherThing = ({ classes, children, className }) => {
  return (
    <p className={`${classes.someOtherThing} ${className && className}`}>
      I'm another thing {children}
    </p>
  );
};
```

I would most likely use the package `classnames` to conditionally render the class name instead of string interpolation.

```
const Something = ({ classes, children, variant }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.someThing}>
      <p> I'm some thing </p>

      <SomeOtherThing />

      <SomeOtherThing className={classes.someOtherThing}>
        I have some children
      </SomeOtherThing>

      <SomeOtherThing className={classes.someOtherThing}>
        I have some children
      </SomeOtherThing>

      <SomeOtherThing className={classes.someOtherThing}>
        I have some children
      </SomeOtherThing>
    </div>
  );
};

const styles = {
  someThing: {
    color: "green",
    border: "solid 2px black",
    margin: 30
  },
  someOtherThing: {
    backgroundColor: "pink"
  }
};
```

Comment: The problem with this solution, is that I have to manually apply that class to every instance of SomeOtherThing.

Comment: It is more maintainable over time

Comment: You do not have to manually apply the class to every instance if you abstract into a new component that pre-defines the class

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple, in your `someThing` CSS codes select the `p` elements with class `someOtherThing` class name and use `not()` CSS operation for `p` in top level, see following code:

```
const styles = {
  someThing: {
    color: "green",
    border: "solid 2px black",
    margin: 30,

    "& [class*='SomeOtherThing']": {
      backgroundColor: "pink" // 
    },

    "& :not([class*='SomeOtherThing'])": {
      fontWeight: "bold" // Just for top level p
    }
  }
};
```

and

```
const SomeOtherThing = ({ classes, children }) => {
  return (
    <p className={classes.root}> I'm another thing {children} </p>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/187l4yl894)

The way that this works, is that by giving `SomeOtherThing` any jss class,  it's going to render the dom element as something like:

```
 <p class="SomeOtherThing-root-0-1-2"> I'm another thing  I have some children  </p>
```

which the `[class*='SomeOtherThing'`] [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) will match on.

You should note that this selector will apply to any deeper nested `SomeOtherThing`s as well.

Comment: I would note that you don't actually need the p selector for this to work. 

What I don't understand, is how that selector is actually working. But this certainly seems like what I want to be doing.

Comment: Ok, I worked it out - and edited the answer to match. You still get the bounty :)

Comment: This will not work under a production build, as the class names will be minified to e.g. `t-root-0`.

Comment: @dwjohnston, Thanks for your bounty assign, yes you right, thanks for your edition.

Answer (score -1):

One problem with the "cascading" aspect of CSS is that it sort of breaks React's component model. But in React you can always create a wrapper or higher-order component that returns another with some predefined props, kind of like a factory function:

```
const Something = props => {
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      // ...
    </div>
  )
}

const SomethingInline = props => {
  return <Something className='display-inline' {...props} />
}

const SomethingBlock = props => {
  return <Something className='display-block' {...props} />
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SomethingInline />
      <SomethingBlock />
      <SomethingBlock> I have children </SomethingBlock>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Instead of using the `&` selector to define your style, create a class that only applies to these specific versions of your component. In this way, the global scope of CSS is avoided and you can create these sort of declarative components that describe their own style, but don't require you to explicitly pass a class name.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I've given an example that can be forked.

Comment: The example you have given is borken.

Comment: I didn't intend to solve the problem for you, but rather to show you a more "React" way of thinking about this problem.