# Set a style property in reactjs for all components of same type

Tags: reactjs, jss

I am getting started with ReactJS and MaterialUI and I am struggling to understand how styling is so different than using CSS.

I mean, in CSS you can define a global rule for all input or select elements, but in ReactJS looks like you cannot do it and you have to pass the class to all elements one by one. I am sure I am missing something, but I haven't found what.

For example, if I have 10 TextField (in fact I am using TextInput from react-admin) in a Form, I would like the 10 of them have the same width without having to declare a `style` object, pass it using `withStyles(style)` HOC and set `className={classes.input}` one by one.

Comment: I've faced this issue before too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I select all react components of a type, without assigning a class to each one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424373/can-i-select-all-react-components-of-a-type-without-assigning-a-class-to-each-o)

Comment: You can import a style sheet into a React app. For example in your `index.js` you can have something like `import "path/to/css/main.css"`

Comment: @wdm - He's talking about jss.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is - there isn't an easy way to do what you want here.

You have a few options:

### Just add the class to each of your components

```
const MyForm = ({classes}) => (
<Form> 
   <TextInput className = {classes.textInput} /> 
   <TextInput className = {classes.textInput}/> 
   <TextInput className = {classes.textInput}/>     
</Form> 
)

const styles = {
    textInput: {
       color: "red" 
    }
}
```

The downside of this is that it is repetitive.

### Style the dom element input directly using a nested selector

```
const MyForm = ({classes}) => (
<Form className={classes.root}> 
   <TextInput/> 
   <TextInput/> 
   <TextInput/>     
</Form> 
)

const styles = {
    root: {
        "& input" {
            color: "red", 
        }
    }
}
```

This here will style the `input` dom element directly - not the React component itself. The downside of this is that you might end up styling inputs that you didn't intend to. However, I've found this the best way to do things like styling tables etc.

### Create your own library of higher order components to wrap the Material-UI components

See this [Software Engineering question of mine.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/381459/is-it-a-good-idea-to-wrap-material-ui-typography-components-in-h1-h2-compon)

```
const MyTextInput = ({classes, ...rest}) => (
    <TextInput className = {classes.root} ...rest/> 
)

const styles = {
    root: {
       color: "red", 
    }
}

const MyForm = ({classes}) => (
    <Form> 
       <MyTextInput/> 
       <MyTextInput/> 
       <MyTextInput/>     
    </Form> 
);
```

This does seem like unnecessary boilerplate etc, but I think in the long run - this is the best approach for a project that is going to be around for a while - in terms of maintaining a consistent design schema across the whole application.